# how to query time-series data in postgresql to find spikes

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a table called cpu_usages and I'm trying to find spikes of cpu usage. My table stores 4 columns:

```
id serial
at timestamp
cpu_usage float
cpu_core int
```

the at column stores a timestamp of every minute ever day.
I want to select all rows where I take  each timestamp and get  the next 3 minutes and if any of the timestamps has a cpu_value over at least 3% higher than the starting value for that timestamp, then return it

So for example if I have these rows:

```
id|at|cpu_values,cpu_core
1 | 2019-01-01-00:00|1|0
2 | 2019-01-01-00:01|1|0
3 | 2019-01-01-00:02|4|0
4 | 2019-01-01-00:03|1|0
5 | 2019-01-01-00:04|1|0
6 | 2019-01-01-00:05|1|0
7 | 2019-01-01-00:06|1|0
8 | 2019-01-01-00:07|1|0
9 | 2019-01-01-00:08|6|0
10 | 2019-01-01-00:00|1|1
11 | 2019-01-01-00:01|1|1
12| 2019-01-01-00:02|4|1
13 | 2019-01-01-00:03|1|1
14 | 2019-01-01-00:04|1|1
15 | 2019-01-01-00:05|1|1
16 | 2019-01-01-00:06|1|1
17 | 2019-01-01-00:07|1|1
18 | 2019-01-01-00:08|6|1
```

It would return rows:
1,2,6,7,8

I am not sure how to do this because it sounds like it needs some sort of nested joins.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: What is the "it"?  The first timestamp or the bigger one?

Comment: the first timestamp

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Just use window functions.  Assuming you want the larger value, then you want to look back not forward:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(cpu_value) over (order by timestamp
                                  range between interval '3 minute' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding
                                 ) as previous_min
      from t
     ) t
where previous_min * 1.03 < cpu_value;
```

EDIT:

Looking backwards, this would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(cpu_value) over (order by timestamp
                                  range between interval '1 second' following and interval '3 minute' following
                                 ) as next_min
      from t
     ) t
where cpu_value * 1.03 > next_min;
```

Comment: Thanks. I definitely do want to go forward because I am trying to take the start data and see if I can predict cpu usage. So I need the start times before the spike happens, not the max values. Is that possible with windows functions?

Comment: @jas . . . It is the same idea.  I added that version to the answer as well.

Comment: I realized I was missing a piece of information. I forgot the cpu_core column, so I am trying to get this data for each cpu core. I couldnt figure out how to modify the queries to make it work with cpu_core, is that possible?